# Throughput issue on Target Kafka topic when using Oracle CDC confluent connector

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, debezium

We are currently planning to implement confluent oracle CDC connector and we are under testing phase. While testing we observed there is throughput issue on Target kafka topic. We tuned multiple parameters but the throughput is not going beyond 450Kbps. Anybody facing issue with confluent oracle cdc connector.

And we also performed testing on debezium oracle connector and we found it to be more stable than confluent oracle cdc connector.

Throughput on Target topic to be optimum

Comment: You would need to first verify with your DBA that your bottleneck is not on the Oracle side executing your SQL, then consider the network latency (fetch size, # of fetches needed, two round trips per fetch, network latency between client and database, do the math to see how much time this represents; if fetch size is small increase it dramatically). Only then would I dig into the client technology itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From mine experience both tools face the same problem. They rely on Oracle Logminer - a diagnostic tool, which was intended for different purpose.

Check DB server, its performance and alert.log and you will find there is one spinning job running Logminer, utilizing 100% of single CPU all the time.

You might play with redolog size, try to add PGA memory(Logminer is memory hungry), but still you wont be able to scale up more. You might not be able to improve performance by starting multiple parallel Logminer jobs.

Try simulate a data purging job. Create huge tabla with some data. Then DELETE that data using single or more conventional DELETE statement(s). This will generate HUGE amount of redo. Check how backlog is growing and how fast can logminer parse generated arch redologs.

The only tools which can do native CDC for Oracle are: GoldenGate, Shareplex and Informatica.

Comment: Not quite true. Debezium connector has ability to read redo log data using OpenLogReplicator (native open source redo log reader) which allows to parse redo log data with speed > 100MB/s

Comment: @AdamLeszczyński wow, thanks for letting me know. Logminer usually parses 30-50MB/s max. Also the tool is infamous for memory leaks in PGA. 
Amazon DMS (which is also based on Logminer) has two pages long list of limitations.
I'm glad thing started finally moving forward.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to test OLR and have some issues - you can contact me directly or submit bugs on GitHub project page. Happy testing.